# CSS everything selector problem with multiple :not()

Tags: css, frontend

there is a problem that I have had since I started using CSS everything selector [*] with multiple [:not()].

Examples below does not work as I tried:

```
.post-body *:not(.has-color):not(.has-bg){
     color: red
}
```

```
.post-body *:not(.has-color)*:not(.has-bg){
     color: red
}
```

```
.post-body *:not(.has-color .has-bg){
     color: red
}
```

```
.post-body *:not(.has-color , .has-bg){
     color: red
}
```

Imagine something like WordPress post content; I can not change the content whole structure but I do need to set a primary color for texts which do not have a specific background or text color. So I am trying to set Red Color to any element except elements that contain ".has-color" or ".has-bg" that is it there is no relation between them.

Has somebody solved this issue or even seemed to something like this?

Comment: Some HTML markup would help... And do you want to exclude which has `.has-color` AND `.has-bg`? `.has-color` OR `.has-bg`? Elements that has  `.has-bg` and is a child of `.has-color`? --- Clarify.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Hi my friend imagine something like WordPress post content;
I can not change the content whole structure but I do need to set a primary color for texts which do not have a specific background or text color.
So I am trying to set Red Color to any element except elements that contain  ".has-color" or ".has-bg" that is it there is no relation between them.

Comment: So that would probably be `.post-body *:not(.has-color), .post-body *:not(.has-bg){ color: red }`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I also tried this but this is just overwriting and do not work for my purpose.

Comment: ok... I just found in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) that `.not()` can handle the OR operator `||`... (experimental !?!). Try: `.post-body *:not(.has-color || .has-bg){ color: red }`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Thanks! yes, multiple selectors for this seem to be experimental! the best trick for using [:not()] multiple times is to write something like SECOND example however it does not work with [*] selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example should work, as shown in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/lseemann/pen/zYKpYQx), but as Louys notes, it’s hard to tell without any markup.

```
.post-body *:not(.has-color):not(.has-bg) {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: The problem was that: ".has-color" had a "strong" tag inside of itself

Comment: I see. Then perhaps you can use the following property to ensure that children of .has-color and .has-bg retain a color of inherit. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/lseemann/pen/zYKpYQx) is updated to demo.

```.post-body *:not(.has-color):not(.has-bg) {
  color: red;
}

.post-body .has-color *:not(.has-color):not(.has-bg),
.post-body .has-bg *:not(.has-color):not(.has-bg) {
  color: inherit;
}
```